# how can i get the value of variable inside function to outside the on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can i take the value from 'a = entry.username' out of the function? i want to get value that already looping inside the function

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
        var usernamelogin = $('#usernamelogin').val()
        var passwordlogin = $('#passwordlogin').val()
        var data_user1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_user'))
        
        for(var i in data_user1){
        var entry = data_user1[i]
        
        if(usernamelogin == entry.username && passwordlogin == entry.password){
            window.location.href = "curhat.jsp"
            a = entry.username
            return
            }   
        }
        if(usernamelogin != entry.username && passwordlogin != entry.password){
            alert("wrong username or password") 
        }
                
        //console.log(data_user1)
        //console.log('username = ' + entry.username)
        
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `a` before you enter the function so that you can use it later as shown below:

```
    let a;
    $('#btnlogin').click(function(){
            var usernamelogin = $('#usernamelogin').val()
            var passwordlogin = $('#passwordlogin').val()
            var data_user1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_user'))
            
            for(var i in data_user1){
            var entry = data_user1[i]
            
            if(usernamelogin == entry.username && passwordlogin == entry.password){
                window.location.href = "curhat.jsp"
                a = entry.username
                return
                }   
            }
            if(usernamelogin != entry.username && passwordlogin != entry.password){
                alert("wrong username or password") 
            }
                    
            //console.log(data_user1)
            //console.log('username = ' + entry.username)
            
        })

//check if a is not null and do something with it
if(a){
  //do something with a here out of the function
}
```

if you wish to pass a across pages, you may use localStorage or sessionStorage as shown below to store the value of a:

```
a = entry.username;

localStorage.setItem("a",JSON.stringify(a))
```

and then later on retrieve it in another page using

```
const val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("a"))
```

Comment: thanks sir it's works, but can i keep the variable to use on next page?
i gonna redirect that page move to another page and use 'a' to insert the value of textbox/ label.

Comment: if(a != null){
  $('#isinama').text('Welcome ' + a)
 }

Comment: if i console.log(a), value already empty

Comment: To pass the variable across screens use the localStorage of the sessionStorage. Look at the edit i made

Comment: An alternative would also be to pass the value of as a query parameter to the url of the next page e.g.  https://example.com/next-page?a=username and retrieving it in the said page using the location.search variable